# Secret Manager Cross Partition Rotation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

**What I'm hoping to achieve**

I have the same secret stored in Secret Manager across three different regions (EU, NA and CN). I'm hoping to enable auto rotation for the secret while keeping eventual consistency across three regions.

**What I have investigated so far**

I learn that I can create a custom lambda to handle the auto-rotation, and I also learn that Secret Manager supports replicating secrets to multiple regions in the same partition.

What I have in mind is using the secret in NA as the primary secret, and the other two regions will use its read replica. Setting this up in the global partition is easy, however since one of our target region is China, things get more complicated.

**Question**

Any ideas or tips on how to achieve cross-partition secret key rotation is appreciated!